# Where are fonts specified in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fonts

I'm teaching myself MVC and am having trouble with the fonts in the output web pages.

I have a View object that starts thus:-

```
@model IEnumerable<Beer.Models.Brewery>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

... etc etc
```

The file `Beer\Views\Shared\Index.cshtml` is:-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```

When I run this the page is rendered in Times New Roman. I then change the Layout to:-

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

which refers to `Beer\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`, which is:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

It then renders in a different font (Helvetica, I suspect). The Visual Studio search and Agent Ransack agree that no source file contains the word "Roman" (it appears in some dlls).

So why is the page being displayed in Times New Roman? Where I should look to find out?

**Edit**

There are two `.css` files in the `Beer\Content` directory. `bootstrap.css` specifies Helvetica for the body; changing that to Courier and then Times New Roman didn't make any difference. `Site.css` doesn't mention fonts at all.

Comment: What font family have you specified in content/css? It is possible that the first font (and perhaps second) is not available to the browser. Use your browser's developer tools to discover what is happening.

Comment: @AndyG, thanks for your reply; I have answered your question in the edit.

Comment: I believe it is in App_Start -> BundleConfig.cs that you can check the configuration for the css bundle. Check that it includes both files. Again, it is your developer tools that will confirm which css files, and which css rules, are in use. Clear the browser cache as well.

Comment: @AndyG, thanks for that. Clearing the cache made changes to `boostrap.css` take effect (groan). Specifying Times New Roman then makes the `_Layout` version render in Times New Roman, but somewhat differently from the Times New Roman for the `Index` version. So the mystery remains, but is less urgent as I can actually influence the output somehow.